# Quickest way to traverse an XML document with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, node.js, xpath

From a similar question I found out about [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_XPath#Node-specific_evaluator_function) and it looks incredibly fast, but I can't use it with Node.js:

```
> var xp = new XPathEvaluator();
ReferenceError: XPathEvaluator is not defined
    at repl:1:14
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at repl.js:249:20
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
```

Can I somehow install it as a module? Or is there an alternative?
The problem is that I'm downloading several RSS feeds with total of about 900 entries. I'm downloading them for less than a second, but iterating over each element with jQuery

```
$(xml).find('entry').each(function() {  });
```

... takes 10-15 seconds, which for a web service isn't acceptable. Any suggestions?

Comment: tried https://npmjs.org/package/xpath ?

Comment: Yes, I found out about it after I posted by question, I should have googled it first. It's working and it's super fast. Post an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need anything for node.js, hit up http://npmjs.org first, to see if it doesn't already exist. For common things like XPath traversal, it usually does. In this case: https://npmjs.org/package/xpath